# How to use secure module (play framework) if the application is having more than one login page

Tags: java, security, authentication, playframework-1.x

Problem - 
 In my application I have two different modules 
  1 - Front end View 
  2 - Back end admin view.
   There are two different login forms for both the modules. And the authentication  process to authenticate the user is also different for both the modules. 
   Now In Secure.java there is only one action/method "login()" to render the login page if the user is not authenticated. Then how should I manage the rendering of the login page of the respective module if the user is not authenticated. I can manage that by customizing the Secure.java class and the route file of the Secure module. But is it a correct method to do that. 
  I have one more query regrading the "check" method. According to the documentation, we need to override the check method in the Security class (which is extended from Secure.Security) in order to check the user's profile. I had done the same i.e. added the check annotation @Check("admin") in the Admin controller and override the method in the Security class. But the check method (overridden method) is never called. why this is so?? Am I getting something wrong here??

Here  is the structure of the Admin class...

```
@With(Secure.class)
@Check("admin")
public class Admin extends JapidContorller {

  /**
  * An action to render the index page of the Back end admin module.
  */
  public static void index(){
     renderJapid();
  }

  /**
   * An action to render the login page of the Back end admin module.
   */
   public static void adminLogin() {
      renderJapid();
  }

  /**
   * An method to log out the logged in user.
   */
   public static void adminLogout(){
      renderJapid();
   }

}
```

And in Security class

```
public class Security extends Secure.Security {
    public static boolean authenticate(String username, String password){
      -----------------
      -----------------
    }

    public static boolean check(String profile){
       System.out.println("[Security]  The check from security is called");
       return true;
    }
}
```

But here the check is never called when I request the Admin.index() page.
So here I need uyour help on two different issue.
1 ) If the application is having more than one login page, then how should we handle the user's authentication using secure module.
2) The overridden check method is never called.

Please help me here. Its really urgent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Deadbolt to add authorisation, and then dispatch to the required login page if and when DeadboltHandler#onAccessFailure is invoked.  Take a look at the integration-with-secure sample application to get an idea on how to do this.

https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt/tree/master/samples-and-tests/integration-with-secure